# Mail server configuration on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, smtp, postfix

This is kind of a basic question and it might sound stupid but I am new to this whole mail server thing and I am trying to learn how to setup one.

I have a VPS server which runs Ubuntu 12.04 (OpenVZ). I want to host few websites on this VPS and want these websites to send out emails correctly.

I want each website to send/receive emails using the domain on which it runs.

```
I.e. If a website is running on example.com I should be able to create emails like info@example.com, query@example.com and should be send and receive emails to these email accounts.
```

Will I have to run my own mail server to achieve this or are there any other solutions which I can use?

Also, the VPS all ready have sendmail configured and is able to send out emails. If I want to install postfix, will I have to remove sendmail?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party email server instead of messing around with trying to set up your own. Google apps http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/, outlook http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-com/, and many other places (I can only post 2 links...) all provide this service. Google is $5/month/user and outlook is free (for now). The exact setup will vary slightly but the basic steps are:

1) set up account with chosen email server provider.

2) Verify that you own your domain example.com. This is usually done with a TXT or CNAME DNS record set at your web host (just follow your yahoo/gmail/outlook instructions).

3) Set your MX DNS records according to your providers instructions.

Note: It can take up to 48 hours for DNS record changes to propogate through the internet.

I'm a big fan of going this route because it means you'll still have email if your webhost is down. Also, if you have your own email server and someone gets in and starts spamming, your site could get blacklisted. Not to mention the fact that its a lot more work to do it all yourself. However, if you feel the need to do it all yourself then more power to ya. Hope this helps!